# Maven & remote windows share repository

Tags: maven, dependencies, share

I have windows share repository (e.g. \myhost\myrepo ) . I would like to retrieve files from this one, but I don't know how.

I included

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>MyRepo</id>
        <name>My Repository</name>
        <url>file://myhost/myrepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and in log I see:

```
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for file://myhost/myrepo
Downloading: file://myhost/myrepo/[groupId]/[artifactId]/[version]/[artifactId][version].jar
```

and build fails due unresolved dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution (maybe it won't work on non_windows machines, but still):

Url tag has to be something like this one:

```
<url>file://\\server\Maven\repo\</url>
```